# Can I use delete clause in Case Clause in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-delete, delete-row

I am newbie to teradata.

I need to delete a row once the case condition is satisfied.

Eg: case condition true delete the selected row.

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what you are trying to accomplish that can't be done with a WHERE clause?

Comment: case when col1=31 then (case when desc= 'xxxxxx' then delete the entire row end) else xxxx end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misinterpreting what you are trying to accomplish with the CASE statement, but based on my understanding you can use the WHERE clause to conditionally remove data from a table:

```
DELETE
FROM MyDB.MyTable
WHERE Col1 = 31
  AND "Desc" = 'xxxxxx';
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment then you need to apply the CASE logic to each column returned in the SELECT statement that you wish to obscure.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col1 = 31 and "DESC" = 'yyyyy'
            THEN NULL
            ELSE ColA
       END AS ColA_,
    /* Repeat for each column you wish to "delete" */
  FROM MyDB.MyTable;
```

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for your quick response  sel 
   xx
  ,yy
  ,zz
  ,case 
        when col1=30 then (case when desc ='yyyy' then aaaa end) 
        when col1=31 then (case when desc= 'xxxxxx' then delete the entire row end) 
        else xxxx end as ll
from mytable
I need to delete the row from which i am selecting